# Why do my menus have little icons next to the items?

Tags: menu

Recently little icons appeared in all my menus, eg the hard drive w/ green arrow next to save, orange folder next to open, etc. This has happened in every file, edit, etc menus for every single application, and its really annoying. Any idea how to shut them off?

*UPDATE*

Ok, I put both of the below settings to menus have no icons, but now the icons are back! I rechecked the setting and they both say they're off, but the icons are still here...

Comment: do you have gnome-shell installed?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do that.

1. If you have gnome-tweak-tool installed, open gnome-tweak-tool
   and select "Theme"

   Unmark "Menus have icons" and "Buttons have icons" 
   [image]
2. If you don't have gnome-tweak-tool installed, and don't want to install it, because it would also mean installing gnome-shell, you can use gconf-editor.

Install gconf-editor with

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

Now, launch gconf-editor

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>gconf-editor

Go to desktop/gnome/interface and unmark buttons_have_icons and menus_have_icons

[image]